# multipath storage changes not see between 2 servers with ntfs-3g

Tags: multipath, ntfs

I have installed centos 6.2 as virtual host with KVM on servers. Each is connected via SCSI cabling to a HP-MSA500-G2. I've mounted the storage box via multipathd on box machines and both machines can see the data ( ntfs-3g ). But when I add a file via server A, server B can't see it unless I unmount and remount the multipath device - what am I doing wrong? It doesn't matter if I tell the file system to sync etc. - any idea?

Answer (score 1):

NTFS isn't a cluster-aware filesystem - it shouldn't be mounted on two systems at the same time.

`ntfs-3g` could probably have some better handling for this situation, but it would just be a hackish workaround - the filesystem format simply wasn't built for this.

Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve with this configuration?

Comment: No kidding? OK, well that explains it. I am actually using the HP-MSA500-G2 as shared storage to allow for live migration of VM's -  it's connected via scsi to to HP G5 machines. I'm converting from bare metal to KVM - and this is part of a proof of concept. I'm learning about storage is the most straight forward answer. So it's easy for me to repartition and reformat to ext4, I just wanted to convince myself that the multipath was working the way I though it should. So ext4 it is. If I am the same problem, I will post!

Comment: Didn't help same problem. The storage devices specs says it definitely supports multiple server access. Admittedly, I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: Multipathing is when a single server has multiple paths to access a device - not when multiple servers access a given device.  EXT4 is not built for access by multiple nodes to the same physical device any more than NTFS is - but that doesn't mean that the storage is failing to provide access to multiple servers.